# How can I use special chars in Python Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure-functions, httprequest

I have an Azure Function (Python) and I need to get special chars in the request.params.

The URL I want to accept is "http://localhost:7071/api/testApp?Status>3"

My Python code is below:

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        Metadata = MetadataOperations()
        result = Metadata.get_items(req.params)
```

This is what I get:

[image: mappingproxy({})]

When the URL is "http://localhost:7071/api/testApp?Status=3" everything is working fine.
[image: mappingproxy({'status': '3'})]

What should I do in order to accept '>' chars?

Thanks.

Comment: The query in the URL has to be [URL encoded](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus). That's BTW required by the HTTP standard, not by Python. Also using something other then the normal `key=value` scheme might result in less convenience features in the framework, e.g. parsing the query into a dict.

Comment: The URL is invalid. This isn't an issue with Azure functions. You tried to use a parameter named `Status>3`. The reason `Status=3` works is because it defines a parameter named `Status` whose value is 3, not a comparison

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use special chars in Python Azure Function?

I do agree with @Klaus D. and I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations.

You cannot directly use **`>`** it in URL. But you can in below way:

**`__init__.py`**

```
import azure.functions as func
import urllib.parse

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        decpar = {k1: urllib.parse.unquote(v1) for k1, v1 in req.params.items()}
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Received query parameters are/Sent Parameters are: {decpar}", status_code=200)
    except Exception as ee:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error: {str(ee)}", status_code=500)
```

http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?Status=%3E3

[image]

You need to give like this : `?Status=%3E3`

```
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?Status=%3E3
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

This way you can use **`>`** but not directly.